# Only satellite internet here in the country

Tags: apt, laptop

Its been almost a year since we moved out to the country. With 10 GB allowance of data, which lasts about a week, we are left with very poor and slow service the rest of the month. 
Tethering our phones is ok, but runs out in about 10 days. No land line service here. No wifi hot spots near either. There has to be a legal way around this limited rationing of data in this great land.
I will appreciate any feedback or guidance!
Thanks to all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing do with Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Waaaay off topic, but I may as well try to drag it on topic.

There are all sorts of technical solutions - have you looked into the price of a leased line, a radio tower, and setting up a local WISP ?

For just using apt, set up a alias or script using apt's `--print-uris` argument can give you a list of URLs to download somewhere else, then just put them into `/var/cache/apt/archives`.  Or even actually support the Debian project and buy CD/DVD sets of releases - stretch just came out, so it is nice and fresh :).  Then just get new CDs every 6 months to a year, and limit your apt use to the security release channel.